# Adding json object via .data() to dynamically added td via jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am using `HTML`, `CSS` and `JQuery`/`JavaScript` to create a table which its `td` is populated during runtime. Depending on the data returned via `Ajax`, only some `td`s are populated. I have added `click` and `doubleclick` event to the populated `td`s. For `doubleclick` event, I need to call a function and pass `JSON object` to it. The JSON data are something like below or [here](https://run.mocky.io/v3/f869037c-1ac6-45c8-9fd4-b9a577fe6b0f)

```json
{
  "is_active": true,
  "timeslots": [
    {
      "department": "department01",
      "end_time": "13:00:00",
      "id": 3,
      "start_time": "09:00:00",
      "number": 1
    }
//... and other timeslots
}
```

Below are the code snippets:

#### HTML:

```html
...
<tr id="department_row">
  <td class="first-column">Department</td>
  <!--                TODO: To add cells via JQuery/JavaScript-->
  </tr>
```

#### JavaScript/JQuery:

```js
$.getJSON(
  "http://url_for_the_data"
).done(function(data) {
  let allDepartmentData = data['timeslots']
  let scheduleRow: string

  for (let singleData of allDepartmentData) {
    scheduleRow += '<td id="td_schedule_'+ singleData.id +'>'+ singleData.trolleys +'</td>'

    // The part I want to add the data to the td
    $('#td_schedule_' + singleData.id).data('slot', singleData);
  }
  $('#department_row').append(scheduleRow)
})
```

Then, after the page is loaded, in Chrome DevTool, I accessed via its console `$('#td_schedule_3').data('slot')` but it gave me `undefined`.  As written in my first paragraph, the purpose is when the `td` with the data is double clicked, the `JSON object` (i.e. `department`, `end_time`, `id`, `start_time` and `number`) will be passed to a function which will call up an Edit Modal with the data from `JSON object`. For simplicity, I do not put in the codes related to the double click event and edit modal.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: `let scheduleRow: string` is a syntax error. Please try to create a [mre].

Comment: Never mind. `scheduleRow` is a string. The fact that it contains HTML doesn't mean you can select it and access the elements; you need to add it to the document first.

Comment: Here's how to do this properly: https://jsfiddle.net/otu13d6q/

Comment: Thanks Chris for correcting my syntax error and the explanation. I referred to  jsfiddle.net/otu13d6q and then, changed to adding the elements to the document. Then, I can access the data already.